# I keep getting a textbox come up when I open a form

Tags: ms-access

When ever I open my navigation form I get this message -
AllDataTableNew.ikk followed by an empty text box and have to just press OK.
AllDataTableNew is a table with all my information in it that I use but I do not know what .ikk means.
If there is any code you want me to submit let me know and I will do my best to supply it but seeing as I have no idea what is causing it I dont know what code to submit.
Thanks, Kieran[image]
edit: added picture for clarity

Comment: I'm not sure how your form is getting it's info but if you're using a query table then check to see if the criteria is in square brackets [ ] because that will make this popup come up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do not have any specific criteria in the query though so I am completely lost!

Comment: Then you might want to just double check typos and verify that each data source in the form is available and real.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referencing a field named *ikk* somewhere in the data source of the form. Maybe a typo?! Access doesn't find that field, and asks for a value.

Comment: I have searched for this ikk field name and cannot for the life of me find it anywhere. Its completely baffling

Comment: Hi, I found a field by that name and deleted it yet i still get the same problem. Is there anyway to delete a field if you cannot find it? thanks

Comment: Where did you find that field? In a table? Query?

Comment: It was just a field in the form called ikk. it was down at the bottom so I didnt see it.

Comment: And the form field was bound to "ikk"?

Comment: yeah its just a field with ikk in it and called ikk

Comment: Yeah its still coming up and I cant even see it there anymore

Answer (score 0):

Access tends to leave "ghosts in the machine" frequently.  You more than likely have a field on a form, or a field in a query, called "ikk".  It is trying to bind to a field in AllDataTableNew.  Believe it or not, you may have to actually delete the entire form and rebuild it.  Sometimes that is the only way I can get rid of the issue, and I've been working with Access since 1995.